# Xcode iPhone app runs and crashes immediately

Tags: ios, crash

Xcode (latest). When runs the app it immediately closes. The app loads on the simulator so the picture appears, but than screen becomes white so the app stacks.  has nothing but the only label and green background.

This is how it look when just started: http://tinypic.com/r/2dvu7io/8

The second later: http://tinypic.com/r/98wp5u/8

```js
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="7702" systemVersion="14D136" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="7701"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Hello World!" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="BkG-X7-MYE">
                    <rect key="frame" x="115" y="289" width="133" height="41"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="25"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="I9t-Ne-eCZ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="146" y="216" width="42" height="21"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.82914447010375036" green="1" blue="0.67541074406557622" alpha="0.70999999999999996" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina47"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="517.5" y="438.5"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Yes, you apparently did *something* wrong. Can you provide some code?

Comment: There is nothing to put. I mean I just put a label on the view (in xib).

Comment: What is the console log  (use cmd+SHIFT+c to launch degugger colsole) ?

Comment: @RahulSharma I used this hot key after program's start and finish but it stills empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is too small to even try all debugging tools in the armor. If I were you I would start with these following steps to eliminate the root cause and investigate into the issue.

a) Try creating a new sample project with same steps that you did in current project and try running it. If all goes well, it might be some glitch with some plugins in XCode,which might have resulted in corrupt files.
b) If the issue persist, try using break point on various methods viz

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
- (void)viewDidLoad
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Most probably these steps should reveal as to what stage do you reach before you reach the stalling screen.